# String-Word counter

Tags: java, string, algorithm, count

I have to print the count of the words in a string which are repeated exactly N times?

example:

one two three four three two five

1

output:3

since one,four and five appears only once.

My code shows me the output as 1.

what is wrong with my code and logic?thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=scan.nextLine(),b;
        int n=scan.nextInt();
        int c=0,f=0,i;
        String[] a=s.split(" ");
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            b=a[i];
            for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
            {
             if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(a[j]))
             {
                c++;
             }

            }
            if(n==c)
            {
                f++;
            }
            else
            {
                c=0;

            }
        }
        System.out.print(f);

    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend stepping through it line by line with a debugger.

Comment: You never reset `i` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three reasons that makes your result incorrect.

First one is `c`
If a word is here once only, then the `if` statement `if(b.equalsIgnoreCase(a[j]))` will never be true. Which means that `c` will be always equal to 0.
So you you need to use `1` as default value for `c` or you should check the value of `c` using the following statement `if (n == c + 1)`

The second point is that you should reset the value of `c` even if it is equal to `n`.

Then with this double for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   b = a[i];
   for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
```

When you searching for a value that is there once only, the last occurence of every words will be counted as well. 
There is lot of ways to solve that. one of them is to use a `Set<String>` and only count for the words that has not been used before.

So at the end you will have something similar to that:

```
int c=1,f=0,i;
String[] a=s.split(" ");
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  b = a[i];
  if (words.add(b)) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (b.equalsIgnoreCase(a[j])) {
        c++;
      }
    }
    if (n == c) {
      f++;
    }
    c = 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It's because you don't initialize C when n==c . Therefor it increases to 1 after one and one are matched. And it's not working well . It should be 0 for every loop
Also why j starts from i+1? After each loop it  will lose comparison one by one Since a[j] is getting smaller. It should always containt list of full input numbers